# Return entries where custom field partially contains

Tags: entries, custom-field, contains

My entries have a field containing a third-party product id and a price, separated by a hyphen, like so:

```
p666a-12.99
```

In the template, a plugin is returning me some product ids, and I want to return all entries containing those product ids. I know I can fetch all entries, reduce the custom field down to the product id and compare it to the product ids returned from the plugin, but that seems a bit tardy.

Can I filter my entries using the custom field directly?

```
{# pluginIds = 'p666a, p678a' #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('sectionName').customField(pluginIds) %}
```

Comment: What's the reason for the product ID and the price being saved to the same database column? Can you change this?

Comment: +1 to @carlcs. If at all possible, I'd separate them out into different fields. :)

Comment: The plugin presents the client with a dropdown list of products from a third-party, and I think a dropdown is the best way to do that. But, yes, ideally I'd populate two database columns using that field - any examples for doing that from a dropdown, within a plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Preparse](https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft) plugin to save the product ID part of your field in a new hidden field.

Add a new "productId" Preparse field to your entry type with this code in the field's settings:

```
{{ entry.customField|split('-')|first }}
```

To update all existing entries, re-save them by going into Settings → Sections → Section Name and click Save.
You can now set up a criteria model exactly like you mentioned in your question, except that you now use the
Preparse field as your custom field parameter:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('sectionName').productId(pluginIds) %}
```

Comment: This could definitely work but I'd love to populate two columns from the one dropdown instead, inside the plugin I've created.

Comment: Well.. I think you should better ask a new question for this problem. I'm not sure I understand how many plugins are involved and how they save.